# Custom Rails Authenticity Token

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, cookies, curl

I am working an a simple server that should save the high scores from an android app. I am having trouble with using cURL because I need to do the request with an authenticity token which changes all the time, so is there a way to set an default token for example "Secret" every time someone tries to do a request at that certain page (Create method) ?
Basically I am trying to do a POST request with parameters to localhost:3000/users which is the create method but I also need to include the token which always changes, is there a way to use a custom one ?

My controller looks like this :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  TOKEN = "secret"

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :score)
    end
private
    def authenticate
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_token do |token, options|
        token == TOKEN
      end
    end

end
```

In my terminal I've used:

> curl http://mysite.com/users/ --cookie-jar cookie | grep csrf

For obtaining the token

```
curl http://mysite.com/users/ --data "user[name]=jelly&user[score]=14&authenticity_token=here_goes_the_token_obtained_before" --cookie cookie
```

and this for making the request

So again is the any way to change the token from here_goes_the_token_obtained_before into "secret" for eq ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround.

In controller:

```
skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token, only: :create
before_filter :verify_token, only: :create
#....
private
def verify_token
   params[:authenticity_token] == MY_CONSTANT_TOKEN
end
```

Though I would suggest You to separate HTML and API(JSON) controllers and use different auth mechanism for each group. It will be much cleaner.

Comment: Thank you, this was a "life saver"!